# The down arrow in the picture below doesn't appear

Tags: javascript, html, css

When I click the orange header's content, the content and the up arrow will hide out but the down arrow will not appear as I expect it. Please help me in fixing it. Here's an image of what I've made and a link to this page:
[Link ex](http://testcode.hvu-forum.info/)
[image]

And here is an image of my page when I click on the orange header again:
[image]

Here is a piece of my JS code:

```js
 $('.test-page .question-answer:first-child .question img').addClass('active');
    $('.test-page .question-answer:first-child .answer').slideDown();
    $('.test-page .question-answer:first-child .question').addClass('active');
    $('.test-page .question-answer:first-child .question .content').addClass('active');
    $('.test-page .question-answer .question').click(function() {
        $('.test-page .question-answer .question img.img-down').removeClass('active');
        $('.test-page .question-answer .question img.img-up').removeClass('active');
        $(this).next().slideToggle().closest('.question-answer').siblings().find('.answer').slideUp();
        $(this).children().toggleClass('active').closest('.question-answer').siblings().find('.content').removeClass('active');
        $(this).toggleClass('active').closest('.question-answer').siblings().find('.question').removeClass('active');
    });
```

Comment: The problem statement needs more clarity.

Comment: When I click the orange header content again, the content and the up arrow will hide but the down arrow will not appear as the content below.